# How to get request string on .net core WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

Help me to get request string when I receive request on web server

Here my code:

```
[Route("membersave/{name}/{username}/{email}/{token}")]
public class MemberSave : Controller {
public TokContext _context { get; set; }
public MemberSave([FromServices] TokContext context) {
  _context = context;
}

[HttpGet]
public bool Get_Member_Save(string name, string username, string email, string token) {
  return DataAccess.Member_Save(_context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString, name, username, email, token);
}
```

}

I want to get string like this `myip/membersave/John&Wick/wick/johnwick@gmail.com/603D3163-DCCA-4FC2-8F85-9A2F94F9A725`

I need to save all requests to db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get request path like that:

```
var path = HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;
```